# Why is there no Chromecast icon in BBC iPlayer and ITV Hub apps on my iPhone?

Tags: chromecast

Both BBC iPlayer and ITV Hub claim that they support Chromecast in the iOS apps.

https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/help/questions/features/chromecast

https://help.itv.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002740874-How-do-I-cast-from-the-ITV-Hub-

But I do not see the Chromecast icon in either app.

[image: BBC iPlayer screenshot]

[image: ITV Hub screenshot]

Chromecasting from YouTube app works fine.

Comment: Have you followed the requirements indicated in the FAQ's you linked?  Please [edit] your question to indicate the requirements for this work and whether or not you meet those requirements.

Comment: The help articles that I linked do not say anything about ‘requirements’ so not sure what you mean. Is it if the Chromecast device is on the same Wi-Fi as the iPhone? This is already answered in my question as Chromecasting from YouTube app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the apps need Local Network permission?

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/102229

Edit: also specifically with iPlayer, it seems the Chromecast icon at first just appears on the iPlayer home screen - if you press it there, it asks to set the iOS local network permission. From then on, the Chromecast icon will appear on programmes. Weirdly, the Local Network permission does not appear in the Settings until you press the Chromecast icon for the first time ... and at first, the Chromecast icon is only on the iPlayer homescreen.